# Blazor Radzen DataGrid custom filtering unhandled exception

Tags: razor, datagrid, blazor, radzen

I have a Radzen DataGrid with three columns: First Name, Last Name, and Service Coordinator. I want the Service Coordinator column to have checkbox filtering. I referred to the [documentation](https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid-filter-template) and tried adapting their code to this problem; however, I am encountering unhandled exceptions whenever I interact with the table.

```
@page "/"
...
@using Radzen;
@using Radzen.Blazor;

<h2>Manage Employee</h2>

<RadzenDataGrid Data="@EmployeeRecords" TItem="ChildRecord"
                AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" AllowFiltering="true" FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EmployeeRecord" Property="Name.FirstName" Title="First Name" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EmployeeRecord" Property="Name.LastName" Title="Last Name" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EmployeeRecord" Property="ServiceCoordinator" Title="Customer"
                              FilterOperator="FilterOperator.Contains" LogicalFilterOperator="LogicalFilterOperator.Or">
            <FilterTemplate>
                <RadzenDropDown @bind-Value=@selectedServiceCoordinators Style="width:100%;"
                                Change=@OnSelectedServiceCoordinatorsChange Data="@(serviceCoordinators)" AllowClear="true" Multiple="true" />
            </FilterTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code {
    List<string> selectedServiceCoordinators;
    List<string> serviceCoordinators = new List<string>();

    EmployeeRecord employeeRecord = new EmployeeRecord();
    List<EmployeeRecord> EmployeeRecords = new List<EmployeeRecord>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        GetEmployeeRecords();
        UpdateServiceCoordinators();
    }
    private void GetEmployeeRecords() {
        EmployeeRecords = EmployeeRecordService.EmployeeRecords();
    }
    private void UpdateServiceCoordinators() {
        foreach (EmployeeRecord c in EmployeeRecords) {
            serviceCoordinators.Add(c.ServiceCoordinator);
        }
    }
    void OnSelectedServiceCoordinatorsChange(object value) {
        if (selectedServiceCoordinators != null && !selectedServiceCoordinators.Any()) {
            selectedServiceCoordinators = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that `selectedServiceCoordinator` is not being updated properly but I'm unsure to remedy this error since I'm relying on Radzen's internal implementation.